# How to create one group on multiple fields in a DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I have a DataGrid in which I am using Grouping.  I can't seem to find anyway to create a group that consists of more than one Field or Column.  For instance say you want to group results by  both Name and Station?  I need the unique combination of both fields to be determining factor in grouping.

The only way I can think of to accomplish this is to create a new property that combines the two for me and then group on that.  This feels like it would be a fairly common request so hopefully I'm just missing something.

Comment: [How to: Group, Sort, and Filter Data in the DataGrid Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff407126(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Yes, and following the example they have there (which I had) creates a group and then a sub group.  It does not create a single group on those two fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The appears to be no way to create a Group on more than one property at a time.  The solution to this is to create a field on your model that represents the combination of those two fields and then group on that.